# Changing mount point of LVM

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to copy a huge data file onto the desktop of a user but I am running out of space though there is enough left in logical partition. I am not very familiar with logical partitions but is there a way to change the mounting so that the users don't run out of space while saving huge files

I have included the outputs of the following commands

`sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="98715d8d-bf13-48f5-882e-36270c539c94" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="qOUDEc-qHDq-y9NL-OWCF-fO04-vnPI-8UNrtV" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="6ulNAl-1Hky-orpE-ntL2-Brgu-Qen1-BYqCIh" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: UUID="73eb8366-c1ed-4bd2-b931-7891a3a855f1" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: UUID="89685a3f-3a67-4b21-9f6f-fe88c04b5175" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: UUID="69e3381b-a2b5-4866-81b6-bd368c9157d5" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="ExtHDD03" UUID="485AA7713243CEFB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="ExtHDD04" UUID="0DFFA1CB15212E12" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="ExtHDD01" UUID="00148BDE148BD4D6" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sr1: LABEL="WD SmartWare" TYPE="udf" 
/dev/sdg1: UUID="485ef4bd-0093-42c5-a3e5-0090e68e93c1" TYPE="ext4"
```

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders, total 488281250 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc648a420

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   488280063   243627008   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000617c8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907028991  1953513472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: 2168.7 GB, 2168656494592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 263657 cylinders, total 4235657216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 27.5 GB, 27481079808 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3341 cylinders, total 53673984 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000558944256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364797 cylinders, total 5860466688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000558944256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364797 cylinders, total 5860466688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sde: 1999.7 GB, 1999696297984 bytes
228 heads, 56 sectors/track, 305894 cylinders, total 3905656832 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe534f55f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  3905656831  1952827392    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdg'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdg: 3000.6 GB, 3000558944256 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364797 cylinders, total 5860466688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

`mount`

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext2 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sde1 on /media/ExtHDD01 type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/ExtHDD03 type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdd1 on /media/ExtHDD04 type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=bhaskar)
/dev/sr1 on /media/bhaskar/WD SmartWare type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077,uhelper=udisks2)
gvfsd-fuse on /home/bhaskar/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1002/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=clevelandclinic)
/dev/sdg1 on /media/clevelandclinic/485ef4bd-0093-42c5-a3e5-0090e68e93c1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on /media/clevelandclinic/89685a3f-3a67-4b21-9f6f-fe88c04b5175 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Content of `fstab file`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /               ext2    errors=remount-ro 0       1

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=00148BDE148BD4D6 /media/ExtHDD01/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0

UUID=485AA7713243CEFB /media/ExtHDD03/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0

UUID=0DFFA1CB15212E12 /media/ExtHDD04/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0
```

sudo df -h

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   50G   19G   29G  40% /  
none                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
udev                           12G   12K   12G   1% /dev  
tmpfs                         2.4G  1.4M  2.4G   1% /run  
none                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
none                           12G   31M   12G   1% /run/shm  
none                          100M  168K  100M   1% /run/user  
/dev/sde1                     1.9T  184M  1.9T   1% /media/ExtHDD01  
/dev/sdc1                     2.8T  1.4T  1.4T  50% /media/ExtHDD03  
/dev/sdd1                     2.8T  2.7T   89G  97% /media/ExtHDD04  
/dev/sr1                      623M  623M     0 100% /media/bhaskar/WD SmartWare  
/dev/sdg1                     2.7T  1.2T  1.4T  47%     /media/clevelandclinic/485ef4bd-0093-42c5-a3e5-0090e68e93c1  
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home  2.0T   71M  1.9T   1%   /media/clevelandclinic/89685a3f-3a67-4b21-9f6f-fe88c04b5175
```

sudo pvs

```
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
/dev/sda2  VolGroup lvm2 a--  232.31g    0   
/dev/sdb1  VolGroup lvm2 a--    1.82t    0
```

sudo vgs

```
VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree  
VolGroup   2   3   0 wz--n- 2.05t    0
```

sudo lvs

```
LV      VG       Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert  
lv_home VolGroup -wi-ao---  1.97t                                             
lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao--- 50.00g                                             
lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao--- 25.59g
```

sudo parted --list

```
Model: ATA WDC WD2500AAJS-7 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags  
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ext4         boot  
 2      525MB   250GB  249GB  primary               lvm  


Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72202 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary               lvm  


Model: WD My Book 111D (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags  
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB  ntfs               msftdata  


Model: WD My Book 111D (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags  
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB  ntfs               msftdata  


Model: WD My Book 1112 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sde: 2000GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs  


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)  
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 53.7GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: loop  

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags  
 1      0.00B  53.7GB  53.7GB  ext2  


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)  
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 27.5GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: loop  

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags  
 1      0.00B  27.5GB  27.5GB  linux-swap(v1)  


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)  
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: 2169GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: loop  

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags  
 1      0.00B  2169GB  2169GB  ext4  


Model: WD My Book 1144 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdg: 3001GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags  
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB  ext4               msftdata
```

Comment: Provide us more information output of # df -h, pvs, vgs, lvs

Comment: your are trying to copy the files to users desktop, desktop located under /home/users/Desktop

Here it need more space.

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: UUID="89685a3f-3a67-4b21-9f6f-fe88c04b5175" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: For the future: Don't use `fdisk -l` any more, but use `parted --list` as fdisk is quite limited.

Comment: @Lonston I have included the outputs of the commands that you have asked for. And yes I am trying to copy the files to /home/users/Desktop.

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for the suggestion, I have included the output of that command too

Comment: Erm, look at the comment with 1 next to it...  Isn't that the answer???

Comment: @Fabby, how do I mount it for all users automatically after a reboot

Comment: I don't understand your question...  It should be mounted already...  Chat?

Comment: @Fabby I would like to chat

Comment: You don't have enough reputation... :(

Comment: Could we use gchat?

Comment: Nope, not allowed (for good reasons)...  Did Lonston's comment help you or not?  (still unclear to me)

Comment: The first user who uses that volume 
dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: UUID="89685a3f-3a67-4b21-9f6f-fe88c04b5175" TYPE="ext4"
can only access it and the rest can't. For example, it is currently mounted under /media/bhaskar. The rest cant access this drive